# Combobox selection filtering datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, combobox

I am trying to filter a `datagridview` using a `combobox`. The idea is that the windows form posts transactions to a table, the `datagridview` will show previous transactions for the selected customer by linking to the table.

code:

```
private void sidcombo_SelectedChangeCommitted(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string connectionString = "server=RUBY;" + "initial catalog=CustomerReports;" + "user id=xxxxxxxxxx;" + "password=XXXX";
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    string customerselected = ("SELECT * FROM transactions_1617 WHERE customer_ID = @customerid");
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(customerselected, conn);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@customerid", sidcombo.GetItemText(sidcombo.SelectedValue));
    conn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
}
```

Would I need to remove the binding source from the DGV as it is populated through this?

Any other way to accomplish this?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

```
var Name =  sidcombo.Items[sidcombo.SelectedIndex].ToString();
```

Comment: ok so add the variable into the selectedchangecommitted and then call use the variable in the Parameters? - sorry pretty new to C#